# I use Valgrind in linux to check leak memory in c but i don't find were is the leak in my function "join"

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I create a function Join who returns a string which is the concatenation of two character strings.
When I use Valgrind in my program I have a malloc leak by join but I don't find where is a leak in the code.

If anyone can help me

```
    char        *join(char *s1, char *s2, int *s_s1, int s_s2)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *str;

    if (!s1 || !s2)
        return (NULL);
    if (!(str = malloc((*s_s1 + s_s2 + 1) * sizeof(char))))
        return (NULL);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < *s_s1)
        str[i] = s1[i];
    j = i;
    i = -1;
    while (++i < s_s2)
        str[j + i] = s2[i];
    *s_s1 += s_s2;
    str[j + i] = '\0';
    free(s1);
    return (str);
}

int get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
{
    static  t_getnl b[256];
    char            *tmp;

    if (fd < 0 || !line || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || read(fd, b[fd].s, 0) == -1)
        return (-1);
    inite_base(&b[fd], line);
    if (b[fd].i == 0 && (b[fd].tmp = gread(fd, &b[fd], line)) <= 0)
        return (b[fd].tmp);
    while (1)
    {
        if ((b[Z].tmp = gwasread(b[Z].s + b[Z].i, b[Z].l - b[Z].i)) < 0)
            *line = join(*line, b[Z].s + b[Z].i, &b[Z].ll, b[Z].l - b[Z].i);
        else
        {
            tmp = ft_subbstr(b[fd].s + b[fd].i, 0, b[fd].tmp);
            *line = join(*line, tmp, &b[fd].ll, b[fd].tmp);
            free(tmp);
        }
        b[fd].i = ((b[fd].tmp < 0) ? 0 : b[fd].i + b[fd].tmp + 1);
        if (b[fd].tmp >= 0)
            break ;
        if ((b[fd].tmp = gread(fd, &b[fd], line)) <= 0)
            return (b[fd].tmp);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: You have only `free`d one of the two strings you are joining. You allocate enough memory for both strings, copy each of the two strings, terminate it, but then free only one of them. But perhaps one of them can't be `free`d, I notice you use different methods to pass their length. But this function is all the information that has been posted.

Comment: Was valgrind in fact telling you that the memory was allocated by join, rather than leaked by join? If so the problem is that some other code did not free what join allocated.